# GCC complaining about non-standard calling convention "ZEND_API"

Tags: c, gcc, header

In Zend engine code for PHP I see lines like the below in the header files.

```
ZEND_API char *zend_strndup(const char *s, unsigned int length) ZEND_ATTRIBUTE_MALLOC;
```

I am new to professional C/C++ programming.

When I try to compile the c files in this package using gcc I get errors like

```
zend_alloc.h:55: error: expected =, ,, ;, asm or __attribute__ before char
```

I tried the command `gcc -I./ -I../TSRM zend_language_*.c`

It looks like gcc is complaing about ZEND_API. What does ZEND_API indicate? Can anyone help me figure out why this error happens?

[SVN repository where the files are located.](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/)

Answer (score 3):

These files are part of the PHP interpreter, and are not intended to be compiled separately from it. The configure script is supposed to define the `ZEND_API` macro to:

```
__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
```

on systems that support it (e.g, GCC 4.0+), and to nothing on other compilers.

If you're just trying to build PHP, download the whole source bundle from php.net and use `configure` / `make` to build it. The build process is complex, and isn't intended to be obvious (or even possible) to run manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I just want to build the zend language parser and use it to work on PHP syntax tree. Is it possible/recommended to do that and how could I compile only part of the package?