# What's the meaning of adding all-caps keywords before a function definition?

Tags: c, syntax

For example, in the Zend PHP source:

```
ZEND_API int _zend_get_parameters_array(int ht, int param_count, zval **argument_array TSRMLS_DC)
```

Comment: If I could have duped this to something I would have, but I guess that's what this is for.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `ZEND_API` is a macro name (previously defined with a `#define` directive), which is expanded by the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor). It's used to establish a meaningful shorthand for a particular set of directives used in the signature of all Zend API functions; this helps ensure that none of them leave that out, which would cause problems with interop code. It can also be (and, I think, is, although I haven't looked at the Zend source) used to abstract platform differences without changing code in all those locations.

Comment: ok,I have litter experience in c project,I got it.define 
ZEND_API __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: I am not sure this answers the question.Yes it is macro, the complete answer would explain its position ahead of a function definition.

Comment: @robbmj: Fair enough. How's that?

Comment: That macro is to mark the function as .dll exportable, so you can use it once you have built the .dll.  instead of using __declspec(dllexport) which is clearly an architecture dependent feature (it works only in microsoft environments) you can #define it depending on other macro values, so it will expand to that in MS environments and to nothing at all when compiling on other environments.

Answer (score 2):

Using a macro in front of a function declaration like that is used to specify calling conventions for certain platforms. In the case of ZEND_API, it expands to

```
__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
```

which tells GCC 4 to make `_zend_get_parameters_array` visible to other libraries.

Functions are normally visible, so this attribute would usually be a no-op. However, when `-fvisibility=hidden` is passed to GCC, the default is to hide functions so that they can't be seen from other libraries. "Visible" or "hidden" describe whether the function will get a symbol table entry. This attribute overrides the effect of `-fvisibility=hidden` by marking a function as visible.*

The `ZEND_API` macro tells GCC to make `_zend_get_parameters_array` visible. GCC does that by putting an entry for that function in the symbol table of the compiled library. Without that macro, the function couldn't be called from another library.

See [Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) for more about the `visibility` attribute of GCC.

*The visibility setting of `default` means visible.

Comment: Many macros is difined like what you said like PHPAPI,but I can't find difine ZEND_API like this in php-src directory. IS it  passed by config or makefile or gcc.

Comment: @memng `ZEND_API` seems to be [defined by configure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9124808/1422127)